# image does not open when button is pressed in actionListener in my GUI?

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am trying to get an image to open when the PlaySci button is pressed so I put the image in the PlaySci action listener, however it only opens when the exit button is pressed?

I have looked at it for hours and still dont understand why, I have tried to get rid of the exit button alltogether but then the image does not show at all.

I made the image into a `JLabel` at the top:

```
ImageIcon scis1 = new ImageIcon("scis.jpg");

private JLabel picture = new JLabel(scis1);
```

Here is the code for my PlaySci button ActonListener:

```
class PlaySciHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        String computerRand = sps.computerChoice();
        txtComputerRand.setText(computerRand);
        String result = sps.play(Sps.SCISSORS);
        txtResult.setText(result);
        picture.setBounds(60, 200, 400, 400);// this is the image I want displayed when the PlaySci button is pressed
        panel.add(picture);
    }
}
```

This is the exit button ActionListener (That for some reason is the only way to display the image):

```
class exitHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, //when this button is pressed the image comes up?
                "Are you sure you want to exit?", 
                "Exit?", 
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if(n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code creating the button and adding the ActionListener:

```
                btnPlaySci = new JButton ("Scissors!");
        btnPlaySci.setBounds(180, 40, 110, 20);
        btnPlaySci.addActionListener(new PlaySciHandler());
        panel.add (btnPlaySci);
        btnPlaySci.setForeground(Color.MAGENTA);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show how did you set the listener to button

Comment: show you code where you are registering the `ActioListener` to the `JButtons`

Comment: Better than last deleted question. 1+

Comment: It still not giving complete picture..Putting whole code of GUI side would make us to understand the reason for this unexpected behavior of your code more clearly..

Comment: Well I put a dropbox link before, here is the whole gui: https://www.dropbox.com/s/462ev2i4whswxwb/sps.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add the `JLabel` in the `class PlaySciHandler implements ActionListener` block.Add it in your `createForm()` method and make it invisible: `picture.setVisible(false);`
and when you want to display after a button click, make it visible : `picture.setVisible(true);`

Answer (score 3):

You should repaint your panel after you add picture to it. See the code for `PlaySciHandler` `actionPerformed` method.

```
class PlaySciHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            String computerRand = sps.computerChoice();
            txtComputerRand.setText(computerRand);
            String result = sps.play(Sps.SCISSORS);
            txtResult.setText(result);
            picture.setBounds(60, 200, 400, 400);// this is the image I want displayed when the PlaySci button is pressed
            panel.add(picture);
            panel.repaint();//Must repaint the panel .
        }
    }
```

**Note:** As a side note I would suggest you to never use `null Layout` for `JPanel`.Use the inbuilt `Layouts` provided by `Swing`. You can get more information about Layouts usage at this [official site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Another one is that always stick with java naming conventions. Class `exitHandler` should be written as `ExitHandler` instead.To know more have a look at this [official site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Comment: The first answer worked for me but thank you for your help and the tip on null layout

Comment: 1+ for the recommendations to avoid null layout.